# Why does Django need to serialize validators

Tags: python, django

When running:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

This will sometimes fail because it can't serialize validators, hence the usage of `python @deconstructible`.

Why do the validators have anything to do with the database, and why are they not just ignored?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/) says: *Django will make migrations for any change to your models or fields - **even options that don’t affect the database - as the only way it can reconstruct a field correctly is to have all the changes in the history, and you might need those options in some data migrations later on (for example, if you’ve set custom validators).***

Comment: @Bakuriu you should post this as an answer, I think it was very helpful.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti Agreed.